# How to figure out which SQLDependency triggered change function?

Tags: sql-server, ado.net, sql-server-2008-r2, sqldependency, query-notifications

I'm exploring query notifications with the `SQLDependency` class.  Building a simple working example is easy, but I feel like I'm missing something.  Once I step past a simple one-table/one-dependency example I'm left wondering  *how can I figure out which dependency triggered my callback?*

I'm having a bit of trouble explaining, so I included the simple example below.  When `AChange()` is called I cannot look at the sql inside the dependency, and i don't have a reference to the associated cache object.

So what's a boy to do?

- **Option 1** -  create a distinct function for each object i want to track and hard code the cache-key (or relevant information) in the callback.  This feels dirty & eliminates the posibility of adding new cache items without deploying new code--ewww.
- **Option 2** -  Use the Dependency `Id` property and a parallel tracking structure

Am I just missing something?  Is this a deficiency in the `SQLDependency` structure?  I've  I've looked at 20 different articles on the topic and all of them seem to have the same hole.  Suggestions?

**Code Sample**

```
public class DependencyCache{
   public static  string       cacheName  = "Client1";
   public static  MemoryCache  memCache   = new MemoryCache(cacheName);

   public DependencyCache() {
      SqlDependency.Start(connString);
   }

   private static string GetSQL() {
      return "select  someString FROM dbo.TestTable";
   }

   public void DoTest() {
      if (memCache["TEST_KEY"] != null ) {
         Debug.WriteLine("resources found in cache");
         return;
      }
      Cache_GetData();
   }

   private void Cache_GetData() {
      SqlConnection         oConn;
      SqlCommand            oCmd;
      SqlDependency         oDep;
      SqlDataReader         oRS;
      List<string>          stuff    = new List<string>();
      CacheItemPolicy       policy   = new CacheItemPolicy();

      SqlDependency.Start(connString);
      using (oConn = new SqlConnection(connString) ) {
         using (oCmd = new SqlCommand(GetSQL(), oConn) ) {
            oDep = new SqlDependency(oCmd);
            oConn.Open();
            oRS = oCmd.ExecuteReader();

            while(oRS.Read() ) {
                  resources.Add( oRS.GetString(0) );
            }

            oDep.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler (AChange);
         }
      }
      memCache.Set("TEST_KEY", stuff, policy);
   }

   private void AChange(  object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e) {
      string msg= "Dependency Change \nINFO: {0} : SOURCE {1} :TYPE: {2}";
      Debug.WriteLine(String.Format(msg, e.Info, e.Source, e.Type));

      // If multiple queries use this as a callback how can i figure 
      // out WHAT QUERY TRIGGERED the change?
      // I can't figure out how to tell multiple dependency objects apart

      ((SqlDependency)sender).OnChange -= Cache_SqlDependency_OnChange; 
      Cache_GetData(); //reload data
   }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First and foremost: the handler has to be set up **before** the command is executed:

```
 oDep = new SqlDependency(oCmd);
 oConn.Open();
 oDep.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler (AChange);
 oRS = oCmd.ExecuteReader();
 while(oRS.Read() ) {
     resources.Add( oRS.GetString(0) );
 }
```

Otherwise you have a window when the notification may be lost and your callback never invoked.

Now about your question: you should use a separate callback for each query. While this may seem cumbersome, is actually trivial by using a lambda. Something like the following:

```
oDep = new SqlDependency(oCmd);
oConn.Open();
oDep.OnChange += (sender, e) =>
{
   string msg = "Dependency Change \nINFO: {0} : SOURCE {1} :TYPE: {2}";
   Debug.WriteLine(String.Format(msg, e.Info, e.Source, e.Type));

   // The command that trigger the notification is captured in the context:
   //  is oCmd
   //
   // You can now call a handler passing in the relevant info:
   //
   Reload_Data(oCmd, ...);
};
oRS = oCmd.ExecuteReader();
...
```

And remember to *always* check the notification source, info and type. Otherwise you run the risk of spinning ad-nauseam when you are notified for reasons *other* than data change, like invalid query. As a side comment I would add that a good cache design does not refresh the cache on invalidation, but simply invalidates the cached item and lets the *next request* actually fetch a fresh item. With your 'proactive' approach you are refreshing cached items even when not needed, refresh multiple times before they are accessed etc etc. I left out from the example error handling and proper thread synchronization (both required).

Finally, have a look at [LinqtoCache](http://code.google.com/p/linqtocache/) which does pretty much what you're trying to do, but for LINQ queries.

Comment: Thanks for the response; I figured a lambda was the ultimate solution.  Good point about setting up the dependency prior to query execution & checking source/type.  Why did you pass the command back into the reload function?

Comment: Duh, scratch my question.  I see the closure you created & the associated comments in code.